# how do I pass url in vue js methods and trigger on @click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Okay so I am doing laravel vue js project and I want to pass a link in a method (code below).
on click of the div, I want to be taken to the site ([www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) as seen below. I have tried some solutions given on similar posts here but no luck.

```html
<template>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" @mouseover="showMe" @mouseout="hideMe" @click="goToMySite">
        <h6 v-show="goTolink === false">Hover Me</h6>
        <h6 v-show="goToLink === true"> Click to visit My Site </h6>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
export default {
    props: [],
    
    data() {
        return {
            goTolink: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        showMe(){
            this.goTolink = true
        },
    
        hideMe(){
            this.goTolink = false
        },
    
        goToMySite(){
            href='http://www.google.com'
        }
    }
}
</script>
    
<style>
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

- Listeners are not at the good place. By setting it on the parent container the link will never appear because its parent is not displayed anymore.
- You should use `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` / `mouseout` which trigger a lot of unnecessary events
- You have to use `v-if` / `v-else` instead of `v-show` in this kind of use case.
- `href` doesn't exists in your `goToMySite` method

Here's a working example :

```html
<template>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;">
        <h6 v-if="! goTolink"
            @mouseenter="showMe">Hover Me</h6>
        <h6 v-else
            @mouseleave="hideMe"
            @click="goToMySite">Click to visit My Site</h6>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [],
    data() {
        return {
            goTolink: false,
            href: 'https://www.google.com'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        showMe() {
            this.goTolink = true
        },
        hideMe() {
            this.goTolink = false
        },
        goToMySite() {
            // Do what you want here, for example
            window.open(this.href, '_blank');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And a snippet (window.open doesn't works here but it's ok in a regular file) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  <div style="cursor:pointer;">
    <h6 v-if="! goTolink"
        @mouseenter="showMe">Hover Me</h6>
    <h6 v-else
        @mouseleave="hideMe"
        @click="goToMySite">Click to visit My Site</h6>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      goTolink: false,
      href: 'https://www.google.com'
    },
    methods: {
      showMe() {
        this.goTolink = true
      },
      hideMe() {
        this.goTolink = false
      },
      goToMySite() {
        // Do what you want here, for example
        console.log(`Let's visit ${this.href}`);
        window.open(this.href, '_blank');
      }
    }
  })
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Some tips by the way :

- Don't use inline styling
- Unless you want to handle the differences between `false`, `null` and `undefined`, you can test if a value doesn't exists using `! value` (and just `value` if you want to know if the variable is defined)
- It would maybe more relevant here to use a `a` tag for your link (and style it so it looks like your `h6`)

You could also handle the `goToLink` value change in some other ways (but these are subjective choices). For example in the template (so you can remove the methods `showMe` and `hideMe`) :

```html
<h6 v-if="! goTolink"
    @mouseenter="goTolink = true">Hover Me</h6>
<h6 v-else
    @mouseleave="hideMe"
    @click="goTolink = false">Click to visit My Site</h6>
```

or

```html
<h6 v-if="! goTolink"
    @mouseenter="goTolink = ! goTolink">Hover Me</h6>
<h6 v-else
    @mouseleave="hideMe"
    @click="goTolink = ! goTolink">Click to visit My Site</h6>
```

or keep only one method for toggling :

```html
<h6 v-if="! goTolink"
    @mouseenter="toggleLink">Hover Me</h6>
<h6 v-else
    @mouseleave="toggleLink"
    @click="toggleLink">Click to visit My Site</h6>
```

```js
methods: {
    toggleLink() {
        this.goTolink = ! this.goTolink;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `location` object of `window`.

```
goToMySite(){
    window.location.href='http://www.google.com'
}
```